# How to create a system dynamic model formula using AnyLogic? for System dynamic model with delay, the model is attached

Tags: system, delay, microsoft-dynamics, anylogic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIapB.png)

Please help with System dynamic model formula for on the attached picture. AnyLogic is used to for simulation.

I am  struggling with the creation of formulas as this is my first time using AnyLogic.

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Welcome again, happy to help